# Why aren't precompiled assets served on Google App Engine Standard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I have a Ruby on Rails GAE app running in standard environment.  When I deploy using a Cloudbuild which watches my github repo, I can see it precompiling assets in the build logs and storing them in `/workspace/public/assets` just as expected.  This only happens if I don't have precompiled assets in my repo too, otherwise the build logs say:

```
Step #3 - "detector": ======== Output: google.ruby.rails@0.9.0 ========
Step #3 - "detector": Rails assets do not need precompilation.
Step #3 - "detector": ======== Results ========
```

My cloudbuild step for deployment is

```
  - id: deploy_to_GAE
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args: ['app', 'deploy', '--project', '${PROJECT_ID}', '--version', '${BRANCH_NAME}', '${_APP_CONFIG}']
```

I also have this handler in my app.yaml

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|html|txt|webmanifest))$
    static_files: public/\1
```

However, after deployment, none of the static assets can be loaded - they all get a 404 response and and the server logs say something like:
`Static file referenced by handler not found: public/assets/star_custom3-bf067f238ca10c6a873fd0bdd42e55a22f65a9842f010d10e55e2e4acb12ae5b.png`

However,  if I precompile locally, and push the precompiled static files to my git repo, then Cloud Build will still deploy successfully (and not precompile assets again per above), and all the assets load properly in my browser.

In both cases, if I "Debug" the version deployed in GAE's web console, I can see what files were actually deployed and see them all right where they belong within /public/assets.  Yet only in the latter case can a web browser access them.

I've also tried adding build steps in my cloudbuild.yaml to precompile assets using a custom Cloud Builder container.  It creates assets in /workspace as expected, but for some reason the `depoly_to_GAE` step above re-precompiles them.

Lastly, if I delete all my precompiled assets locally, then manually deploy to GAE with
 `gcloud app deploy app-ticket.yaml --project={my project}`, the Cloud Build logs show it precompiling, and just like above, the assets are not reachable by the web browser (404 errors)

When the `deploy_to_GAE` build step precompiles assets, it also sets `RAILS_ENV=production`, however, the actual environment for the rest of the deployment and the env var set in the app.yaml file is `RAILS_ENV=staging`.   I don't think this should matter though.

Why does the built-in asset precompiler for GAE result in usable static assets?

**UPDATE:**
Even when deploying locally with `gcloud app deploy` and no `/public/assets` folder, I can see that cloudbuild will compiled assets, and *appear* to put them properly in `/public/assets`:

However, when using [the GCP Debugger](https://console.cloud.google.com/debug), I notice that the path uses a literal "/" in the folder name instead of making a subfolder.  This seems to be a flaw in the GAE builder:
[image]

I would expect "assets" folder to be properly nested under "public" rather than a mutant folder named "public/assets".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that GAE does some undocumented magic with precompiled assets by not only auto-precompiling them at build-time, but also by creating routes to those assets without needing to add handlers in app.yaml.  Once I removed the handler show in the main question (and copied below), then everything worked as expected:  If I had no `/public/assets` folder, then `gcloud app deploy` would precompile assets automatically, and so long as I didn't try to make a handler, then it would serve those assets properly.

Answer (score -1):

This question would be better suited to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) since it would be easier to investigate and get a proper and thorough answer and also to check the project with their tools and get a better support regarding the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that out and post what I find here as an answer.

Comment: "Open a Support Case" is not an answer; if that's the only way to proceed just post a comment.